# Attachments in mails sent via App Engine not readable on every mail client/ device

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blackberry, attachment, vcf-vcard

I'm using App Engine with Python. My application basically sends *vcards (.vcf)* by email when users request it.

Indeed, files with .vcf extension are supported by App Engine. I use the mail API to send them as attachment. Before, I stored them as db.Blob().

**Problem:**
Most of the time, Blackberry users cannot read the vcards sent as attachments by my application. At the bottom of the mail, it displays: *"application/X-rimdeviceAddress Book:"* and when you click on the file, it says: "This type of attachment cannot be opened on your device".

**Exception:**
A blackberry that receives a vcard serialized from a Blackberry can open it.

Fortunately, it perfectly works on the iPhone and (most of the time) on Android phones.

As vcards serialized from a Blackberry can be correctly opened by Blackberry users, I guess I'm doing something wrong during the storage and/ or the mail dispatch. Or maybe, the MIME type is not correctly set by App Engine methods...

Can someone give a few leads to investigate this pretty annoying problem (I was expecting a pretty big user base on Blackberry phones...)?

Comment: Have you tried sending a vcard to yourself from your blackberry and from App Engine and examining the raw messages? The differences should give you an idea what it is that the blackberry is expecting but not getting.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. I took a look at what differs between both vcards. The one serialized from a Blackberry and readable with a Blackberry is in format 2.1. The vcards that aren't readable are in the format 3.0... Problem: most of the vcards are in 3.0 format right now. Does someone some good python parser that can convert a 3.0 vcard to a 2.1 vcard? (conclusion: it has nothing to do with App Engine)

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out. You should post this as the answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously as I mentioned on my comment above:
- it has nothing to do with Google App Engine
- some devices are just not able to read vcards in format 3.0

But I haven't found a good parser/ converter so far (from vcard 3.0 to vcard 2.1 in python) so if anyone knows one, please let me know. Otherwise, I'll have to build it myself...

Answer (score 0):

What is the code you are generating the vcard with?
if I send a vcard from my blackberry device to an e-mail (opening it on a PC)

if I inspect the code with Notepad++

I spot the diffrents:

```
   X-SALUTATION:Mr/Miss
        X-HomeAddress1:HomeAddressStreet
        X-HomeAddress2:
        X-HomeCity:HomeAddressCity
        X-HomeState/Prov:HomeAddressStateProvince
        X-HomeZIP/PostalCode:1234 AA
        X-HomeCountry:HomeAddressCountry
        X-URL:http://www.url.com
```

How do you mentioned these lines in your Generate code?